# problem with message appearance in the second user screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io-1.0

[sending message code (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pd1t.png)

[first and second user screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ91G.png)

[backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyHrN.png)

when I send hey from the first user it must appear in the second user screen but that didn't happen for some reasons that I couldn't find out

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.